# How to add multiple edges from one vertex in a single traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have three `user` vertices. Tom and Mike `follow` Bob.

```sh
g.addV("user").property(single,"name", "bob")
g.addV("user").property(single,"name", "tom")
g.addV("user").property(single,"name", "mike")
g.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "tom").as("tom").V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "bob").addE("follow").from("tom")
g.V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "mike").as("mike").V().hasLabel("user").has("name", "bob").addE("follow").from("mike")
```

I'd like to add an `alert` with edges to the users. There should be an edge from Bob to the `alert`, and the `alert` should have edges out to the users that `follow` Bob.

```sh
g.V()
.hasLabel("user")
.has("name", "bob")
.as("bob")
.in("follow")
.as("followers")
.addV("alert")
.as("alert")
.addE("alert")
.from("alert")
.to("followers")
.addE("alert")
.from("bob")
.to("alert")
```

What I end up with is two `alert` vertices. Bob has an edge to each of these new `alert` vertices, and the alerts have edges out to Tom and Mike (the followers).

I believe this is because when I select the followers, it branches (?) the traversal and starts creating the duplicates but this is not what I want. How do I construct this traversal to make the appropriate selections but only create a single `alert` vertex? What I'm trying to get is this:

```
       bob
        |
        v
      alert
     |     |
     v     v
   mike   tom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the duplicates come from the fact that `in('follow')` produces two traversers and thus `addV('alert')` gets called multiple times. There are many way you might resolve this, but here is the approach that came immediately to mind for me:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel("user").
......2>   has("name", "bob").as("b").
......3>   addV("alert").as('a').
......4>   addE("alerted").from("b").
......5>   select('b').
......6>   in("follow").
......7>   addE("alerted").from("a").iterate()
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[8]
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:user,name:bob]
==>[id:2,label:user,name:tom]
==>[id:4,label:user,name:mike]
==>[id:8,label:alert]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:6,label:follow,IN:[id:0,label:user],OUT:[id:2,label:user]]
==>[id:7,label:follow,IN:[id:0,label:user],OUT:[id:4,label:user]]
==>[id:9,label:alerted,IN:[id:8,label:alert],OUT:[id:0,label:user]]
==>[id:10,label:alerted,IN:[id:2,label:user],OUT:[id:8,label:alert]]
==>[id:11,label:alerted,IN:[id:4,label:user],OUT:[id:8,label:alert]]
```